# Restructuring data using apply family of functions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have inherited a data set that is 23 attributes measured for each of 13 names (between-subjects--each participant only rated one name on all of these attributes).  Right now it's structured such that the attributes are the fastest-moving factor, followed by the name.  So the the data look like this:

```
Sub#    N1-item1  N1-item2  N1-item3  […]   N2-item1  N2-item2  N2-item3
1       3         5         3               NA        NA        NA
2       NA        NA        NA              1         5         3
3       3         5         3               NA        NA        NA
4       NA        NA        NA              2         2         1
```

It needs to be restructured it such that it's collapsed over name, and all of the item1 entries are the same column (subjects don't matter for this purpose), as below (bearing in mind that there are 23 items not 3 and 13 names not 2):

```
Name    item1     item2     item3
N1      3         5         3               
N2      1         5         3
```

I can do this with loops and, but I'd rather do it in a manner more natural to R, which I'm guessing would be one of the apply family of functions, but I can't quite wrap my head around it--what is the smart way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)#loads libraries
library(tidyr)
dat %>% #name of your dataframe
 gather(key, val, -Sub) %>% #gathers to long data, with id as Sub
 filter(!is.na(val)) %>% #removes rows with NA for the value
 separate(key, c("Name", "item")) %>% #split the column key into Name and item
 spread(item, val) #spreads the data into wide format, with item as the columns

  Sub Name item1 item2 item3
1   1   N1     3     5     3
2   2   N2     1     5     3
3   3   N1     3     5     3
4   4   N2     2     2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Spin the column names around to be `itemX-NY` and then let `reshape` sort it out:

```
names(dat)[-1] <- gsub("(^.+?)-(.+?$)", "\\2-\\1", names(dat)[-1])
na.omit(reshape(dat, direction="long", idvar="Sub", varying=-1, sep="-"))

#     Sub time item1 item2 item3
#1.N1   1   N1     3     5     3
#3.N1   3   N1     3     5     3
#2.N2   2   N2     1     5     3
#4.N2   4   N2     2     2     1
```

Where the data was:

```
dat <- structure(list(Sub = 1:4, `item1-N1` = c(3L, NA, 3L, NA), `item2-N1` = c(5L, 
NA, 5L, NA), `item3-N1` = c(3L, NA, 3L, NA), `item1-N2` = c(NA, 
1L, NA, 2L), `item2-N2` = c(NA, 5L, NA, 2L), `item3-N2` = c(NA, 
3L, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("Sub", "item1-N1", "item2-N1", "item3-N1", 
"item1-N2", "item2-N2", "item3-N2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame
```